# string is undefined and executes in console (json to html)

Tags: javascript, json

I have the below code for creating some simple JSON data, and iterating it over into my page's HTML.

The problem is this code is returning *'string' undefined error* without the on load function.

*With* the on load function present, it is seemingly just ignored and doesn't execute at all (no errors), however, when I add the below code directly into the browser console it executes fine.

Any thoughts?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    var json =[{
                "Name": "sample data",
                "Type": "lorem ip sum lorem sample",
                "DateModified": "6/14/2218 17:22:50",
                "Size": "2 KB",
            }, {
                "Name": "sample Q",
                "Type": "lorem ipsum",
                "DateModified": "5/11/2218 7:32:10",
                "Size": "6999 KB",
            }, {
                "Name": "sample x",
                "Type": "blah blah",
                "DateModified": "6/26/2218 10:29:59",
                "Size": "8999 KB",
            },
    ];

    var string ="";

    for (i in json) {
        string +='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" value="all"></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-4"><span class="folders">'+json[i].Name+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3"><span class="directory">'+json[i].Type+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3"><span class="date-stamp">'+json[i].DateModified+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1"><span class="date-size">'+json[i].Size+'</span></div></div>';
    };
    document.getElementsByClassName('change').innerHTML =string

});
```

Comment: Recommended reading [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is here

```
document.getElementsByClassName('change').innerHTML = string
```

The [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array like object (HTMLCollection) and would need an index, e.g.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('change')[0].innerHTML = string
```

*As mentioned, looping an array with `for..in` is not good (its for objects), so here I used `forEach`, and instead of `getElementsByClassName` I used [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)*

Stack snippet

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    var json =[{
                "Name": "sample data",
                "Type": "lorem ip sum lorem sample",
                "DateModified": "6/14/2218 17:22:50",
                "Size": "2 KB",
            }, {
                "Name": "sample Q",
                "Type": "lorem ipsum",
                "DateModified": "5/11/2218 7:32:10",
                "Size": "6999 KB",
            }, {
                "Name": "sample x",
                "Type": "blah blah",
                "DateModified": "6/26/2218 10:29:59",
                "Size": "8999 KB",
            },
    ];

    var string ="";

    json.forEach( function(item) {
        string +='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" id="all" name="all" value="all"></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-4"><span class="folders">'+item.Name+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3"><span class="directory">'+item.Type+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3"><span class="date-stamp">'+item.DateModified+'</span></div><div class="col-md-15 col-sm-1"><span class="date-size">'+item.Size+'</span></div></div>';
    });
    
    document.querySelector('.change').innerHTML = string

});
```

```html
<div class="change"></div>
```

Comment: You could use querySelector instead, since you're scenario is so simple:

document.querySelector('.change').innerHTML = string;

Comment: @DevinFields True, thanks ... updated with a note and code sample

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   //do work
});
```

Comment: No comment.....